# Wicket 1.5 compared to 1.4

Tags: java, frameworks, wicket

What are the wicket 1.5 new features in short as compared to the most recent 1.4 release?

The first release candidate will be released very soon. We're thinking about the introduction of wicket in one of our projects, so for me it's relevant to see what's coming up in 1.5 and if it's worth to build our software on top of the upcoming 1.5 release or based on the stable 1.4.

Comment: It's too early for this question; Wicket 1.5 hasn't officially been released yet. The available downloads are just milestones.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus I am not your opinion. see updated question of details.

Comment: Compared to the tons of "best web framework?" and "Wicket or X?" questions on SO, this one is actually very specific (answerable) and potentially useful. So +1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a **work in progress** wiki page that answers this question over here: https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/migration-to-wicket-15.html

Comment: that page 404's now. New page: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+1.5

Answer (score 1):

There's a Wicket 1.5 wishlist [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/wicket-15-wish-list.html). Some items have been scored out, suggesting that this list more or less accurately represents what's in 1.5.